# Memory allocation of string Builder. What happens in memory? StringBuilder vs String

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

Possibly a duplicate as there are a lot of questions on this topic but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I know `String` is immutable and `StringBuilder` is mutable. And I understand the essence of these two terms. I wanted to know what exactly happens in the memory when I create an instance of `StringBuilder`. Like:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
```

1. How much space is reserved for s in the memory ?
2. I can use it like `s[0] = 'a';` so can we call s an array ?
3. If s is index-based does that mean characters are stored in memory on consecutive locations ?
4. If answer to 3 is yes. Then what happens if we use `s.Append("abc");` and there isn't enough consecutive space in memory for `"abc"` ? Will it take `s` to a new memory location just like what happens with `string` every time we append something to `string` type variable?

Comment: You can look at the source: [constructor here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,ec674e2123a44860,references) and the indexer [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,fdc8eb61b5bf468a,references). Internally a `char[]` is used which will be "resized" if needed, source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,bb3473794f7408f5).

Comment: The presence of an [indexed property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C# simply indicates that it has been implemented. The implementation of the indexed property might be substantially different to that which you'd find in (for instance) an array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `StringBuilder` is in reality, under the hoods, a chain of `StringBuilders` (think of them as chained blocks of memory). The user is apparently interacting with one single `StringBuilder` but that is far from true.

Each `StringBuilder` uses an underlying `char` array and new `StringBuilder`s will be added to the chain when capacity is depleted.

Keeping that in mind, the answers to your specific questions would be:

1. Check out the implementation to see what the default capacity of a `StringBuilder` and therefore it's underlying array is. You can also specify it with a constructor overload to suit your specific needs.
2. Yes, `StringBuilder` under the hoods uses an array, but each builder in the chain will have its own array.
3. Yes and no. Memory for the array of each internal builder in the chain is allocated consecutively, but the different memory blocks need not be and most likely will not be allocated consecutively.
4. When there isn't enough space a *new* `StringBuilder` is added to the chain and its corresponding array is allocated wherever the runtime sees fit; typically the new builder will at least double the total capacity of the `StringBuilder` and the new array will most likely not be allocated consecutively to the previous one.

Obviously this system allows dynamic resizing while avoiding the costs associated with resizing arrays and copying data back and forth.

Comment: very elaborate answer. Thanks. cleared most of the things. So it's like a linked list ? Node representing array and next pointer pointing towards next array ? wouldn't it be slow traversing it and maintaining all the pointers and implementing indexers on it ?

Comment: StringBuilder definitely uses more RAM than a single char[] but ... when used iteratively to add more string data, it causes less memory fragmentation, so is the recommended method for manipulating strings.

Comment: @Sam Yes, indexing and traversing are obviously slower but a `StringBuilder` is a lot more memory efficient compared to working with `string` in the scenarios it is meant to be used in; for instance dynamically building long strings that require numerous concatenations. But yes, one thing compromises the other, nothing is free obviously. TBH though, in my day to day use of `StringBuilder` indexing is not something I would usually use and I rarely traverse (`ToString()`) more than once.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder allows the allocation of non-contiguous memory to provide the perception of a single contiguous string. I believe internally its a set of pointers to fragments of strings, which are reassembled when you call "ToString" the treatment of array indexes is just a wrapper around the maths. When you .Append() it just grabs a block of new memory and places the string fragment inside it, maintaining an index list of the fragments and their lengths

Comment: That will slow it down ? won't it ? And according to the research I did I found out that if there is alot of append operation is going on in your program you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `string` . Doesn't that contradict with the slowness of keeping the pointers.

Comment: @Sam on the contrary. Its is much faster to create chunks. The key here is choosing a good default capacity (too big, you'd be wasting space, too small and you'd be creating too many chunks). If you were to keep all data in one single array (consecutive in memory) how would you deal with increasing capacity when needed? Remember *arrays have a fixed size, you can't make them grow*. You'd need to allocate a *new* array with more capacity and then *copy all data* from the old depleted one to the new one. That seems much slower. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Whether or not its faster - it prevents memory fragmentation because the large char[] are not stored in a single contiguous block. Eventually if you use too many large simple type arrays you will fragment the large object heap and your program will get OutOfMemoryException even if you have massive RAM free.